# Get position of dynamically added button

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem Statement:**
I have dynamically placed buttons on my spreadsheet using Macro. When I click on the button, it displays the position of the button. Inside the macro, I am also inserting new rows that changes the position of the button. But when I click on the same button which has changed its position due to insertion of a new row, it shows the older position only that was stored during it's creation.

How to make the button show new position each time, taking into account that new rows can be added anytime?

**Piece of my Code:**

```
Sub AddWithin(ByRef pr As Integer, ByRef pc As Integer, ByRef parentCont As Integer)

    MsgBox "Row=" & pr & " Column=" & pc

    Dim r As Integer        'row number
    Dim c As Integer        'column number
    Dim cn As String        'column name
    Dim i As Integer        'looping var
    Dim ContNum As Integer      'value taken from another sheet that keeps count of number of buttons added to the worksheet

    Dim nr As Integer      'New Row Number for new button
    nr = pr + 2

    'Inserting 2 rows below parent container and shifting all cells down
    Rows(nr).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    Rows(nr).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

    'Taking the last container number (ContNum) from Sheet2, incrementing it by 1 and adding it back to the Sheet2
    ContNum = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = ContNum

    'New position for adding a new button
    r = nr
    c = pc + 1

    'Adding a + button to the 1st column
    Dim btn As Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim t As Range
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(r, c))
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With btn
        .OnAction = "'AddWithin " & btn.TopLeftCell.Row & "," & btn.TopLeftCell.Column & "," & ContNum & " '"
        .Caption = "+"
        .Name = "Button" & ContNum
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True            
End Sub
```

**Screenshots of the output:**

[Position of button before adding new rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5eKo.png)
[image]
[Position of button after adding new rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQGmG.png)
[image]

Comment: once you are done adding the button just use `MsgBox btn.TopLeftCell.Address ` or use the button name `MsgBox Sheet1.Shapes("Button1").TopLeftCell.Address `

Comment: Thanks.. This worked.. :)